# rails 3.0.1 active_record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How is it possible with active_record?

```
u = User.all
u = u.where(:id => 1)
```

> NoMethodError: undefined method `where' for #
>   u.class
>   => Array

Can't chain conditions :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `all` method executes the query. So you can't chain after using it.

```
u = User.where(:id => 1)
u.where(:id => 2)
```

This would execute the query `WHERE id = 1 AND id = 2`

Comment: thank u so much! is it possible to make .all query without executing it? )

Comment: You can use User.scoped:    

ree-1.8.7-2010.02 > User.scoped
  SQL (0.5ms)  SHOW TABLES
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`
 => [#<User id: 1, email:.....

Comment: @nopolitica all queries are .all. They're restricted by the where previously provided before. So you can do : `User.where(:id => 1).all`

Comment: I just wanted to add that you still have the old finders available - User.find(params[:id]) isn't going anywhere, for example.  It's only adding the hash of parameters (order, conditions, limit, etc) that are being deprecated.  And remember that User.where(:id => 1) will return an array (like all the new query chains), not that single object.